# how to implement scroll based trigger in wpf?

Tags: wpf, xaml

trying to do some scroll based trigger , how to achieve a custom routedevent trigger raise/fire based on scroll position ( top , middle , bottom ,  value )

with top , when element enter into top scroll view

bottom , when element enter into bottom scroll view

middle , when enter into middle scroll view

value , reach a specific scroll position

my purpose is to mimic some scroll based trigger animation for wpf

Answer (score 0):

I see three solutions:

1. Custom Trigger (from System.Windows.Interactivity)
2. Custom attached event
3. Attach to ScrollViewer.ScrollChanged event in codebehind and play animation from there (animation can still be defined in xaml)

### 1. Solution using Custom Trigger

```
<ScrollViewer x:Name="ScrollViewer1">

</ScrollViewer>


<i:Interaction.Triggers>
    <my:ScrollEventTrigger SourceName="ScrollViewer1 
                           VerticalOffset="0">
       <ei:ControlStoryboardAction Storyboard="{StaticResource ScrolledTopAnimation}" ControlStoryboardOption="Play"  />
    </my:ScrollEventTrigger>

    <my:ScrollEventTrigger SourceName="ScrollViewer1 
                           VerticalOffset="0.5" Unit="Relative" ">
       <ei:ControlStoryboardAction Storyboard="{StaticResource ScrolledToMiddleAnimation}" ControlStoryboardOption="Play"  />
    </my:ScrollEventTrigger>

</i:Interaction.Triggers>
```

```
public class ScrollEventTrigger  : System.Windows.Interactivity.EventTrigger
{
    public ScrollUnit Unit { get; set; }

    public double VerticalOffset { get; set; }


    protected override string GetEventName()
    {
        return "ScrollChanged";
    }

    protected override void OnEvent(EventArgs eventArgs)
    {
        var args = (ScrollChangedEventArgs)eventArgs;
        var scrollViewer = (ScrollViewer)args.Source;

        var verticalOffsetAbs = VerticalOffset;
        if (Unit == ScrollUnit.Relative)
        {
            verticalOffsetAbs = VerticalOffset*scrollViewer.ViewportWidth;
        }

        //you have to play more with this condition, because you may scroll directly from 0.4 to 0.6 and the 0.5 can be skipped.
        if (args.VerticalOffset == verticalOffsetAbs)
        {
            base.OnEvent(eventArgs);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: it is what i need thank you ! second solution is best for my requirement :)

Answer (score 0):

I see three solutions:

1. Custom Trigger (from System.Windows.Interactivity)
2. Custom attached event
3. Attach to ScrollViewer.ScrollChanged event in codebehind and play animation from there (animation can still be defined in xaml)

### 2. Solution using Custom attached event

Advantage of this approach is, that you can easily use this in control styles.
Disadvantage is, that you can't configure exact position when the event has to be triggered and is must be hardcoded.

```
<ScrollViewer x:Name="ScrollViewer1">
    <ScrollViewer.Triggers>
        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="my:ScrollViewerExtension.ScrolledTop">
            <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource ScrolledTopAnimations}" />
        </EventTrigger>
        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="my:ScrollViewerExtension.ScrolledToMiddle">
            <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource ScrolledToMiddleAnimations}" />
        </EventTrigger>
     </ScrollViewer.Triggers>


</ScrollViewer>
```

```
public static class ScrollViewerExtension
{
    public static readonly RoutedEvent ScrolledTopEvent = EventManager.RegisterRoutedEvent("ScrolledTop", RoutingStrategy.Bubble, typeof(RoutedEventHandler), typeof(ScrollViewerExtension));
    public static void AddScrolledTopHandler(DependencyObject d, RoutedEventHandler handler)
    {
        ((UIElement) d).AddHandler(ScrolledTopEvent, handler);

        var scrollViewer = (ScrollViewer) d;

        scrollViewer.ScrollChanged -= ScrollViewer_ScrollChanged; //to avoid multiple subscription
        scrollViewer.ScrollChanged += ScrollViewer_ScrollChanged;
    }

    public static void RemoveScrolledTopHandler(DependencyObject d, RoutedEventHandler handler)
    {
        ((UIElement)d).RemoveHandler(ScrolledTopEvent, handler);
    }

    static void ScrollViewer_ScrollChanged(object sender, ScrollChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.VerticalOffset == 0)
        {
            ((UIElement)sender).RaiseEvent(new RoutedEventArgs(ScrolledTopEvent, sender));
        }
        //else if... trigger other events
        //else if 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I see three solutions:

1. Custom Trigger (from System.Windows.Interactivity)
2. Custom attached event
3. Attach to ScrollViewer.ScrollChanged event in codebehind and play animation from there (animation can still be defined in xaml)

### 3. Solution using code behind

Of course, we can't forget about the simplest solution using code behind. Just compare number of code needed with the other solutions:

```
void ScrollViewer1_ScrollChanged(object sender, ScrollChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.VerticalOffset == 0)
    {
        ((Storyboard)FindResource("ScrolledTopAnimations")).Begin();
    }
    //else if... trigger other animations
    //else if 
}
```