# Add Handler method not being called when Routed Event is attached

Tags: wpf, vb.net, attached-properties, routed-events, attachedbehaviors

I'm trying to create an attached behavior to add an auto-complete list to the standard `TextBox` control. My goal is that every time the `TextChanged` event is raised, my `AutoCompleteBehavior` class creates a popup and fills it with potential auto-complete results.
To get these results, my `AutoCompleteBehavior` declares the following event:

```
Public Shared ReadOnly AutoCompleteListRequestedEvent As RoutedEvent =
                  EventManager.RegisterRoutedEvent("AutoCompleteListRequested",
                  RoutingStrategy.Bubble,
                  GetType(AutoCompleteListRequestedEventHandler), GetType(AutoCompleteBehavior))
```

The above is meant to be an attached event, used like this:

```
<TextBox lib:AutoCompleteBehavior.AutoCompleteListRequested="EventHandlerHere"/>
```

The idea is that when `TextChanged` is raised, `AutoCompleteBehavior.AutoCompleteListRequested` is also raised, which asks the implementing program to supply a list of suggestions for the current input.

For this to work, I have to hook in to the `TextBox.TextChanged` event as soon as my attached event is attached to said `TextBox`. Per [Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/attached-events-overview#defining-your-own-attached-events-as-routed-events) I should be able to declare a sub `Add*Handler` and `Remove*Handler` where the "*" is the name of the attached event, and these would be called whenever the attached event is added or removed from an element.
So  right below the event declaration I have:

```
        Public Shared Sub AddAutoCompleteListRequestedHandler(TB As TextBox, handler As AutoCompleteListRequestedEventHandler)
            'Code to hook into TextBox.TextChanged
        End Sub

        Public Shared Sub RemoveAutoCompleteListRequestedHandler(TB As TextBox, handler As AutoCompleteListRequestedEventHandler)
            'Code to unhook fromTextBox.TextChanged
        End Sub
```

My problem is `AddAutoCompleteListRequestedHandler` is never called. If I call `TextBox.RaiseEvent` to raise `AutoCompleteListRequested`, the event handler defined in XAML does get called (so the event is attached), but it seems my `AddAutoCompleteListRequestedHandler` is completely skipped.

As a final note, I found this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32506913/attached-event-add-handler-method-doesnt-get-called-if-its-defined-in-class-li) which seems to be describing the same problem (my code is also in a dll just like his), but it's two years old and was never answered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The XAML processor won't call your static methods when hooking up the event handler.

If you want to do something when the `TextBox` raises the `TextChanged` event, you would probably be better off implementing an attached behaviour and hook up to the `TextChanged` event in the `PropertyChangedCallback` or in the `OnAttached()` method depending on which kind of behaviour you create.

Please refer to my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51726402/using-same-handlers-for-multiple-objects-wpf-c-sharp/51726597#51726597) for more information about attached behaviours.

Comment: I was not familiar with Blend Behaviors, I will look into those and mark this as the answer if it works out. But I would also like to know _why_ my static methods "wont be called". The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/attached-events-overview#defining-your-own-attached-events-as-routed-events) I linked in my post seems to indicate they should, so what am I missing there?

Comment: I also found an example of using the attached event the same way: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32270426   And it does not work either. And I'm very curious why?

Comment: And yet the static handlers have to be there or XAML won't compile it. How silly.